# How to parse dates in highcharts from csv

Tags: javascript, datetime, charts, highcharts, timestamp

I have a csv data in the following format

```
time_stamp,"Phase 3","Phase 2","Phase 3"
"2014-06-03 07:59:48",24210,22744,26003
"2014-06-04 07:59:49",112603,103417,121368
"2014-06-05 07:59:50",21302,20165,23317
"2014-06-06 07:59:50",21561,20951,23875
"2014-06-07 07:59:03",408,1151,767
"2014-06-08 07:59:04",384,1151,767
```

I am using `highcharts` to generate a graph from these values. I want to parse the `timestamp` into a format that Highcharts will process. I have looked around but couldn't find anything.

**Below is my code snippet:**

```
$.get("<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?php echo $username; ?>"+TimeofDay, function(data) {
        // Split the lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');

        // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(',');

            // header line containes categories
            if (lineNo == 0) {
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo > 0) {
                     options.series.push({
                              name: item,
                              data: []
                              });
                     }
              });

                } else {
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo === 0) { 
                            options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                        } else if (parseFloat(item/1000)) { 
                            options.series[itemNo - 1].data.push(parseFloat(item/1000));
                        } else if (item == "null") { /* adding nulls */
                            options.series[itemNo - 1].data.push(null);
                        }
                    });


                }
            });
```

Any help will be appreciated. I know that I have to convert the timestamp string to date but i'm not sure how.

Comment: In case when you push your dates as categories, you dont need to parse dates to timestamps. It is required when you xAxis is datetime type.

Answer (score 3):

Put the code at the appropriate place in your code where you need to do this conversion.
You have to convert the timestamp string to valid javascript date as below for example:

```
var my_date = "2014-06-03 07:59:48";
my_date = my_date.replace(/-/g, "/"); //here the new date string would be like: 2014/06/03 07:59:48
//alert(my_date);
var javascript_date = new Date(my_date);
```

Comment: Let me know if you find any problem !

Comment: let me give this a shot

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it works for you ! Else let me know if you are still facing the problem in implementing this solution.